# Collectd - multiple JMX ports

Tags: plugins, jmx, collectd

I need to collect data using a JMX plugin. I want to use the same metric names but collect data from different JMX ports on a single host. However, I need a way to differentiate what process JMX is collecting this data from. In  my connections, I have the following Connection blocks specified (Different ports configured). Is there a way to configure JMX to print out the ports or some other unique info to tell me where it is collecting the memory pool data from? Using different Mbeans for each is not an option. I'd like to use some form of tagging so the process ID or port number is sent out as a tag from Collectd. Thanks for your time in advance

```
<Connection>
      Host "localhost"
      ServiceURL "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:17264/jmxrmi"
      Collect "memory_pool"
    </Connection>

<Connection>
      Host "localhost"
      ServiceURL "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:9095/jmxrmi"
      Collect "memory_pool"
    </Connection>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since version 5.0 of the plugin you can put in an InstancePrefix section into the Connection block

```
<Connection>
        Host "localhost"
        ServiceURL "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:17264/jmxrmi"
        Collect "memory_pool"
        InstancePrefix "port17264"
</Connection>
```

Detailed here under the Connection Block section: https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:GenericJMX